# User friendly output for errors

Tags: php, error-handling

I need some help with my error handling in PHP. I develop a software for time tracking using the MVC pattern. This means that I include some template files, after all the work has been done in the controller. These PHP templates are include by `require_once $templatePath.$hash['template']['file']` and contain a simple mixture of HTML and PHP.

Now my problem is, that on errors (not exceptions), my HTML output has been parsed until the error occurs. Now the user sees only some fragments of the site. I've set an own error handling with `set_error_handler( array($this, 'handleErrors') );` which writes the errors to my database an then stops the PHP execution.

Now I want an clean output for the user, but how to remove the current output so far? In case of errors I want to show a special message output for the user. If this doesn't work I want the user to be redirected to an static HTML site (template).

Any ideas how to realize this?

EDIT: The errors I handle with my function are for example warnings by usage of array keys that doesn't exist or notices about deprecated functions etc.

```
[8] Undefined index: email at ../users.tpl in line 51
```

Normally this kind of errors shouldn't occur ... but in case of I want a nice output for users.

Comment: Can you specify the errors you having ?

Comment: Production code should not have errors; they are for debugging (the point is that you fix or detect them and handle the situations yourself). Unless you mean errors which you have specified manually (e.g. "that user doesn't exist" or whatever), in which case you have full control over the output anyway.

Comment: Simplest point would be to do all your error checking before the output, then, if an error has occurred, output the error with its own template. This would mean writing all your output to a buffer variable, then writing your output at the end when it's complete without errors.

Comment: @stslavik: How could I do this? Actually I'm writing my output directly by including my templates with `require once`. So I need to execute the code in my template files before PHP executes it. Could I do this with some kind of `eval`?

Comment: I have to agree with Dave that you shouldn't be having errors, I've never found a need to do this. Particularly with things like deprecated functions, the way to avoid those warnings is just not to use them, that's not a user error...

Comment: I agree too, but that's not the point. If somebody installs my tool on it's own system (using PHP 5.3 for example) and my tool was written using PHP 5.1 and in the meantime some functions were marked as deprecated, or some other kind of error happens, then the user should get a user friendly message and the error or notice should be logged. Also on errors which were not found during software tests...

Comment: That makes a bit more sense, although I'd still say someone installing your code would be better off testing it and checking their server's error log before going live with it, instead, if they have access to their server's logs, at any rate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use output buffering: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php .
Start it the first place you expect output (any HTML, messages, etc.) to user.  Either flush (send to user) or clean (discards) the output buffer, depending on whether everything is successful or there is an error and your error function is called.

For example:

```
function handleErrors(){
    //whatever you're doing to log

    ob_end_clean();

    //Whatever you do to output your standard error page and stop execution.
}
```

Comment: That could be an acceptable answer. At least it works, but is this a really good solution? Are there any disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with content rendering before the error and I tried to use output buffering and it seemed not to work so what I did was redirect the user to a nice error page which said that an **UNEXPECTED** error had occurred. In your case you will obviously first register the error and then redirect if you choose to use my method.

Best regards.

Comment: That's an option, too. But how to do? I know how to write a redirect to the HTTP header, but in my case some lines of my site has already been sent to the client.

Comment: well you can either try using output buffering or just echo a script tag like so

`<script>window.location = 'redirect'</script>` @LingLing

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, all of your output ends up as a string at some point. So when we talk about buffering all your content, at a very high level we're talking about withholding your output to flush it to the user at the end. I'm sure there are a thousand and one different ways to do this... But let's consider a very basic idea, and consider the MVC format.

Let's say that I have my basic page, index.php, through which everything (by means of mod_rewrite or similar) gets sent. Index.php is the beginning and the end; it initiates the calls to the controllers, and displays the results from the views.

If my index.php starts by calling a controller, that controller might be the "users" controller, found at http://www.example.com/users. This is, of course, http://www.example.com/index.php?p=users, and may carry some post data to query a DB.

So index.php may look like:

```
<?
$buffer = file_get_contents( 'templates/header' );
$error = "";
// Load the "users" controller
$controller = $registry->loadController($_GET['p']);

// Returns false on error
$temp = $controller->getBiographyByName( $_POST['name'] )
if ($temp) {
  $buffer .= $temp 
} else {
  $error = "An error occurred while attempting to load Biography for ".$_POST['name'];
}
// do everything else...

if( $error !== "" ) print( $error );
else print( $buffer );
```

I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible, and am assuming there's some background logic ($registry) which handles finding and loading the proper controllers. Those controllers will dictate which models are used, and which templates are loaded to the view. The idea is though to buffer everything and to only output if the content is okay to be displayed.

Again, this is very simplified, but I hope it helps.